# Php/MySql find/replace utf-8 string in json

Tags: php, mysql

I have this json string in a row in mysql database

```
{"editor":"<p>\u067e\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0645<\/p>"}
```

And want to find this and replace with `<a>` tag, but for test, I just select it but look like it can't find it, I used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%\u067e\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0645%'
```

What is the problem?

This is original query:

```
$keyword_j = "\u067e\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0645";

$sql2 = "UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(meta_value, '".$keyword_j."', '<a href=\"\/".$link."\">".$keyword_j."<\/a>') WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%".$keyword_j."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put escape sequence to achieve this. In Mysql, there is a second layer of escaping involved. So use this

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%\\\\u067e\\\\u062f\\\\u0631\\\\u0627\\\\u0645%'
```

To automatically search and replace slash, use this

```
<?php
$keyword_j = "\u067e\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0645";
$x = str_replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\", $keyword_j);
echo $x;
?>
```

**Update Query**

```
$str = addslashes(htmlentities("<a href='".$link."'>".$keyword_j."</a>"));

$sql2 = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value ='".$str."' WHERE meta_value LIKE '%".$x."%'";
```

Comment: Right. with this query it found. but one thing, how can I escape variable? $keyword_j ? I can not do this manually, I mean add some slashes, is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Okay, nice. one last thing, in UPDATE query, should escape everywhere? I used `$keyword_j` 3 times, should use `$x` instead of all? or just use in `LIKE` ? because I used `$x` for all, it didn't nothing

Comment: No. your existing update query is fine. Don't change it. It should not be `$x`. In your case `$keyword_j` is fine for update query

Comment: But it won't update, nothing changed with UPDATE query. It run without error but nothing changed