# Replacing String with Apostrophe in MySQL When running a find and replace query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table called my_table with 2 fields ID and dbtext.

The fields in the database are:

ID: 1
dbtext: Hi this is Bobby's Stuff

I am trying to find and replace text within the dbtext field.  Here is my code:

```
$findtext = 'Hi this is Bobby\'s Stuff';
$replacetext = 'Hi this is Larry\'s Stuff';

$findtext = stripslashes($findtext);
$replacetext = stripslashes($replacetext);



  $sql = "UPDATE my_table SET dbtext = REPLACE(dbtext,'" . $findtext . "','" . $replacetext . "') WHERE ID = '" . $ID . "' ";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Unfortunately when I strip the slashes, the query won't run due to the single quotes breaking the query.

However, if I don't strip the slashes, the query wont find a match as there is no slash in the database.

How do I handle this and make sure it will work with single quotes and double quote situations?

Comment: If performance is not critical for this task, consider fetching the rows and updating via `wpdb::update()`. Calling entire string queries asks for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql follows triple-slash pattern for extra security. Try the code below

```
$findtext = 'Hi this is Bobby\\\'s Stuff';
$replacetext = 'Hi this is Larry\\\'s Stuff';

  $sql = "UPDATE my_table SET dbtext = REPLACE(dbtext,'" . $findtext . "','" . $replacetext . "') WHERE ID = '" . $ID . "' ";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Comment: The triple slash worked when I added them manually.  Trying to sort out how to add them dynamically though.  Tried `$findtext = preg_replace('(/\\\\/)','(/\\/)',$findtext);` Plus other versions of this, but not having any luck.

Comment: Check this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110568/php-mysql-find-replace-utf-8-string-in-json/63110781#63110781

Comment: @CRAIG You can also use this `$e = str_replace("'", "\\\\\'",$findtext);
`